# Background Slideshow z-index obstructing main content

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, z-index

Hello been trying to get  a background slideshow to run on pages in a site it works fine, except for the fact there's nothing backgroundy about it it continuously obstructs the main content no matter how much i change the z-index values. The only elements that come in front of it are only the ones usig jquery. it uses the slides js plugin, pls help troubleshoot, you can view the code at the following link http://www.doxang.org/slidetest.html. Pls help fix the problem with code samples if possible.

Comment: so how is it supposed to look? please provide a screenshot demonstrating the issue.

Comment: if you mean the following elements background image isn't visible, it's because the image fails to load... .slider-wrapper #slider-shadow

Comment: you can see it live if you follow the link

Comment: sorry link not updated will update and send it in a moment

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the following elements background image isn't visible, it's because the image fails to load...

```
.slider-wrapper #slider-shadow
```

also:

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider
```

requires at least:

```
z-index:1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys sorted out